# reload rails stack in development for requests through custom middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, middleware, rails-3.1

I am using a custom Rack middleware in my Rails 3.1 app that wraps around a vanilla Rails controller:

in `routes.rb`

```
stacked_router = 
  Example::Middleware::StackedRouter.new(ProductsController.action(:show))

match '/:id', :to => stacked_router
```

in `example/middleware/stacked_router.rb`

```
class Example::Middleware::StackedRouter
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    # ... do stuff before forwarding the request, then
    @app.call(env) # forward the request
  end
end
```

This works fine.

However there is a catch: When I now change code in `ProductsController`, the changes are *not* picked up automatically. I have to restart the app manually (`touch tmp/restart.txt`)

What's the way to tell the Rails stack that it needs to reload this piece of middleware whenever code is changed?

Comment: After I updated my answer, I was curious as to whether I could repro the problem, and I couldn't. I set up a new 3.2 project with a Product scaffold, added a router like yours, and products controller still reloaded fine. I tested both index and show, and it definitely picks up changes. Maybe this info helps in the game of "where is it not" :)

Answer (score 2):

The tool you want is [autoload](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-autoload). When Rails reloads in dev, it iterates through autoloaded and explicitly defined 'unloadable' constants and removes them (the [watch stack](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/WatchStack.html) manages this).

In your plugin's main lib directory, ex. `lib/stacked_router.rb`, if you declared:

```
autoload Example::Middleware::StackedRouter, 'lib/middleware/stacked_router'
```

I think you *should* get the behavior you're looking for.

Note that if you don't like autoload (people argue it interferes with the ability to monkeypatch), you can mark a constant ([unloadable](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#M000013), then require the file with `load` (just using `require` won't pick up the file the second time).
 or  + `load`. This would also load the class every request in prod, so maybe conditionally load or require depending on env? Autoload is probably the better choice IMO.

Note that I found the [actual Rails code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb) (not Rails documentation) to be the best reference for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Pow you can use the powder gem to easily restart Pow without the need to execute touch `tmp/restart.txt` command. See https://github.com/Rodreegez/powder.

Comment: this works, of course.  But that also restarts the whole app, which is slow.  

When I route to regular Rails controllers (instances of `ActionController::Base`) Rails is smart enough to detect changes. But I've not yet found how Rails does that.

Comment: don't use Pow for development then :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Rails is loading the copy of ProductsController at the moment the server is started into your middleware, and keeping that cached copy. I am not 100% sure about this, but what happens when you try to load the middleware with a proc? e.g.

```
stacked_router = Proc.new {
  Example::Middleware::StackedRouter.new(ProductsController.action(:show))
}
```

That should hopefully make it load a new middleware (and a new ProductsController) on each request. It probably will be unhelpful in production. I don't have similar code in front of me, so I can't test this.